# How do I put a dynamic number of nodes in a Famo.us Engine scene graph?

Tags: famous-engine

I'm trying to add an arbitrary number of nodes onto a FamousEngine Scene Graph. And I need the number of child nodes to be mutable as elements are added and removed. Think lazy loading list...

In the old paradigm, any object with a render function could be tacked onto the "render tree" as long as it returned an array of "renderables". That returned array could change in length and composition frame to frame and the Engine would update the DOM accordingly.

But the new Famo.us "Mixed Mode" FamousEngine has changed a lot. How do I do this now?

Comment: Prior to the time of your question, there is not an answer other than "You need to create the layout components". Currently the engine only has the core components for building your Scene Graph. Famo.us has not created those UI layout Components in the library.  Whether there is a plan to create them in their framework or other libraries is still not clear.

Comment: Thanks. I'm happy to build layout components, but don't have the knowledge to do that. Are there any resources/documentation that could point me in the right direction? All the examples and explanations of components always adds a fixed number of nodes to the scene graph. How do I go about adding a dynamic number of nodes. I assume this is possible as it's done by the framework through its $repeat behavior. But short of digging though the frameworks source, I haven't found an explanation of how it's done.